# Writing LOGS in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server. I'm writing a stored procedure that executes a series of queries. I want to LOG the execution time of every query. Is it possible? Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for using a logging table:

> create procedure procedure_name 
>  as
>  begin
>       declare @start_date datetime = getdate(), 
>                    @execution_time_in_seconds
>   int 
>      /*your procedure code
>   here*/ 
>       @execution_time_in_seconds =
>   datediff(SECOND,@start_date,getdate()) 
>        insert into your
>   logging_table(execution_time_column) values(@execution_time_in_seconds)
>  end

Answer (score 2):

The engine is already keeping stats of execution in [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx). Before you add heavy logging like insert into a log tabvle inside your procedure, consider what can you extract from these stats. The contain values for:

- execution count
- execution time (elapsed)
- work time (non-blocked actual CPU time across all CPUs in parallel queries)
- logical reads/writes
- physical reads
- number of rows returned

This kind of information is significantly richer and more useful for performance investigation that what you would log in a naive approach. Most metrics contain the min, max and total value (and with execution count you also have the average). You can immediatly get a clue what are expensive queries (the one with large elapsed average), which are queries that block often (elapsed time much higher than work time), which cause much writes or much reads, which return large results etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the time stamp via `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and log it before and after the statements you want to execute and then log them and later compare them to see and of course with meaningful messages indicating what started and finished when. Or if you want to see it also you could use this: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME OFF` this one I use in query analyser.

Depending on what you exactly want you need to figure out where to store these messages for logging. Like a table or some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

use PRINT & GETDATE to log the execution time info

example:

```
    DECLARE @Time1 DATETIME
    DECLARE @Time2 DATETIME
    DECLARE @Time3 DATETIME
    DECLARE @STR_TIME1 VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @STR_TIME2 VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @STR_TIME3 VARCHAR(255)

    --{ execute query 1 }
    SET @Time3 = GETDATE()
    --{ execute query 2 }
    SET @Time2 = GETDATE()
    --{ execute query 3 }
    SET @Time3 = GETDATE()

    SET @STR_TIME1 = CONVERT(varchar(255),@Time1,109)
    SET @STR_TIME2 = CONVERT(varchar(255),@Time2,109)
    SET @STR_TIME3 = CONVERT(varchar(255),@Time3,109)

    PRINT 'T1 is' + @STR_TIME1
    PRINT 'T2 is ' + @STR_TIME2
    PRINT 'T3 is ' + @STR_TIME3
```